# Mysqld process not showing all options on command line in CentOs 7

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysqld, centos-7

Mysqld process showed all config file options on command line in CentOs 5 and CentOs 6. But it's not showing the same in CentOs 7. I am using mysql 5.7.21 on CentOs 7 example stated below and 5.7.19 on CentOs 6 example stated below.

centos 6:

```
mysql@xxxxxxxx ==> ps -ef | grep 3306
mysql    23084     1  0 Jan16 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --socket=/datadata/mysql.sock --port=3306 --max_allowed_packet=100M --datadir=/datadata --pid-file=/datadata/mysqld-qa.pid --max_connections=500 --open-files-limit=8192 --thread_cache_size=64 --delayed_insert_limit=4096 --query_cache_limit=1M --query_cache_size=32M --query_cache_type=1 --log_queries_not_using_indexes=off --log-error=/datalogs/mysql-error.log --expire_logs_days=3 --sort_buffer_size=2M --join_buffer_size=4M --read_buffer_size=2M --read_rnd_buffer_size=2M --tmp_table_size=64M --max_heap_table_size=64M --lower_case_table_names=0 --myisam_sort_buffer_size=16M --innodb_file_per_table --innodb_buffer_pool_size=1G --innodb_open_files=600 --innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct=10 --innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0 --innodb_log_file_size=64M --innodb_log_buffer_size=4M --innodb_log_files_in_group=3 --innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT --binlog_cache_size=64K --transaction_isolation=REPEATABLE-READ --server-id=3664 --log-bin=mysqldb01.bin --log-slave-updates --binlog_format=statement --sysdate-is-now=1 --sync-binlog=1 --sync-master-info=1 --log-queries-not-using-indexes=1 --innodb_buffer_pool_instances=5 --innodb_concurrency_tickets=1000000 --auto_increment_increment=10 --auto_increment_offset=2 --binlog_checksum=none --sql_mode=STRICT_ALL_TABLES --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp --open_files_limit=10000 --max_connections=4000 --table_open_cache=400 --binlog_format=statement --log_timestamps=SYSTEM --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp --master_info_repository=table --relay_log_info_repository=table --relay-log=dbtemp02-relay-bin --mysqld_safe_log_timestamps=SYSTEM --slave_net_timeout=3600 --default_password_lifetime=0 --relay_log_recovery=ON
mysql    27230 23084  0 Jan16 ?        00:32:37 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/datadata --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --max-allowed-packet=100M --max-connections=500 --thread-cache-size=64 --delayed-insert-limit=4096 --query-cache-limit=1M --query-cache-size=32M --query-cache-type=1 --log-queries-not-using-indexes=off --expire-logs-days=3 --sort-buffer-size=2M --join-buffer-size=4M --read-buffer-size=2M --read-rnd-buffer-size=2M --tmp-table-size=64M --max-heap-table-size=64M --lower-case-table-names=0 --myisam-sort-buffer-size=16M --innodb-file-per-table --innodb-buffer-pool-size=1G --innodb-open-files=600 --innodb-max-dirty-pages-pct=10 --innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit=0 --innodb-log-file-size=64M --innodb-log-buffer-size=4M --innodb-log-files-in-group=3 --innodb-flush-method=O_DIRECT --binlog-cache-size=64K --transaction-isolation=REPEATABLE-READ --server-id=3664 --log-bin=mysqldb01.bin --log-slave-updates --binlog-format=statement --sysdate-is-now=1 --sync-binlog=1 --sync-master-info=1 --log-queries-not-using-indexes=1 --innodb-buffer-pool-instances=5 --innodb-concurrency-tickets=1000000 --auto-increment-increment=10 --auto-increment-offset=2 --binlog-checksum=none --sql-mode=STRICT_ALL_TABLES --explicit-defaults-for-timestamp --max-connections=4000 --table-open-cache=400 --binlog-format=statement --log-timestamps=SYSTEM --explicit-defaults-for-timestamp --master-info-repository=table --relay-log-info-repository=table --relay-log=dbtemp02-relay-bin --slave-net-timeout=3600 --default-password-lifetime=0 --relay-log-recovery=ON --log-error=/datalogs/mysql-error.log --open-files-limit=10000 --pid-file=/datadata/mysqld-qa.pid --socket=/datadata/mysql.sock --port=3306
```

centos 7:

```
[mysql@xxxxxx binlogs]$ ps -ef | grep mysql
mysql    16343     1 44 00:42 ?        00:53:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld --defaults-group-suffix=@0 --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld-0.pid
```

Any idea how to display all variables in CentOs 7.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be relying on the OS processlist to display mysqld options in the events other versions of the OS do not display them (as your questions points out)

What other methods can you use that are OS-independent ???

## METHOD #1

If you enabled [show_compatibility_56](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html), then login to MySQL and run

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.global_variables;
```

## METHOD #2

If you did not enable [show_compatibility_56](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html), then login to MySQL and run

```
SELECT * FROM performance_schema.global_variables;
```

## METHOD #3

From the OS command line, use [mysqladmin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqladmin.html) utility with `variables` command

```
mysqladmin -h127.0.0.1 -P3306 --protocol=tcp -uroot -p variables
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: So CentOS 7 flavor wont display them due to security purposes.  right?

Comment: Centos 7 doesn't display them because it stopped using a hugely hacky script like `mysqld_safe` to start services. `my_print_defaults  --defaults-group-suffix=@0  --mysqld` will probably also display the values changed in configuration files from the shell.

Answer (score 1):

`SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;` works on all versions of MySQL on all operating systems.  When run from the commandline 'mysql' tool, the output is a few hundred lines something like:

```
+--------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name            | Value |
+--------------------------+-------+
| auto_increment_increment | 1     |
| auto_increment_offset    | 1     |
| autocommit               | ON    |
| automatic_sp_privileges  | ON    |
...
```